# how to solve these two quadratic equations

Tags: numerical-methods, quadratic-forms, quadratics

Can someone help me find the solution for these two quadratic equations ?

1. $ 2(z^2) \ - \ 3.023bz \ + \ 0.115(b^2) \ + \ 2.0814b \ + \ 0.142z \ - \ 0.5856 \ = \ 0 $
2. $ 6.0828(z^2) \ + \ 2.0414bz \ + \ 1.0207(b^2) \ - \ 1.0345b \ - \ 4.0836z \ + \ 1.048 \ = \ 0 $

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Avitus I expressed z in terms of b but the equations are too complex to solve, is there any other easier method.

Comment: For both 1. and 2. $z$ is the variable; both equations are quadratic in $z$. Do you know how to solve a quadratic equation? Please have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Is $ \ b \ $ a variable, or an unspecified constant?  Are these equations to be solved individually, or simultaneously in a system (as we would do to find intersection points between the parabolas represented)?

Comment: yes b is a variable we need to find values of both b and z
they should be solved simultaneously

Comment: can anyone suggest me how can i proceed further

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of tricky solving a multidimensional non-linear equation, i.e. a non-linear system of algebraic equations.

If you want to solve numerically, you can apply some iterative procedure like bisection method or Newton method to find roots numerically. You can find more information (along with the code) here: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/104332/AplMat_34-1989-1_3.pdf

Let me know if you need help with the implementation.